# Firebase project schedule for permanent deletion, cannot be cancelled

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a project on Firebase and today I received an email,
sating that If I do not restore the deletion some time today, it will be permanently deleted.

The email provides a link to restore the data.
However, when I try to restore, the operation fails with an unknown error.

**I am assuming the worst, losing all the data. Outch! this is going to hurt.**

I do believe that it has to do with my recent cancelation of my "GSuite"
email domain, which has been cancelled.

I can still access the Firebase console (using my non GSuite email address) and the project is listed but the database is not showing and also the project permission is not accessible.

*I am guessing if the restore operation is failing, it does not mean the
permanent delete operation is going to fail.*

Any help please as I have no Paid for support with Google.

Comment: I can confirm the the current Email address I am using is an owner of the project;
I have just logged in and grabbed screenshot showing the two email address who are owners. (My current email (2nd entry) and the 1'st entry the cancelled GSuite email).

Comment: Firebase also provided free support, precisely for cases like this. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be sent to Firebase support. There is nothing a regular visitor to Stack Overflow can do about this.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have reached out to support and they have responded. They are looking into this, but they cannot promise a "safe" return just yet.

If this "experience" does not benefit others, then I agree that the question should be closed, or altered at least to "How to avoid your "Firebase" data from deletion when de-linking a GSuite account". But I cannot post that question as I do not have details why this has happened yet.